# Non-Optional expression of type used in check for optionals

Tags: ios, swift3

```
let rootInfo = realm.objects(StoreRealM.self).filter(msg)
    var root = [StoreRealM]()            
    for i in 0 ..< rootInfo.count {
        if let result = rootInfo[i] as? StoreRealM {
            root.append(result)
        }
    }
```

`if let result = rootInfo[i] as? StoreRealM` on this line I get it. I also get

> Conditional cast from 'StoreRealM' to 'StoreRealM' always succeeds

Comment: The simplest solution in your case is `root = rootInfo` thats it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since root only can contain `StoreRealM` objects (guaranteed by the compiler), you do not need to cast the index access to this type; even more, it cannot contain `Optional<StoreRealM>` objects.

So it should be sufficient to write the for loop:

```
for i in 0 ..< rootInfo.count {
    let result = rootInfo[i]
    root.append(result)
}
```

Comment: `for result in rootInfo`